# Default filter from scorecard to another scorecard

Tags: filter, performancepoint, default-value, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer 2013. 
I have two scorecards, primary and secondary as shown in the following figure.

[image: Fig: Primary and Secondary Scorecards]

Fig: Primary and secondary scorecards.

The primary scorecard at left has Date dimension in the rows.
The secondary scorecard at right has City dimension in the rows.
Both of them have common measures, viz. Previous Snapshot and Current Snapshot which are calculated members from SSAS cube.

I have connected the Date dimension from the primary scorecard to the Page level of secondary scorecard. When I click any date from the primary scorecard, the data in secondary scorecard changes accordingly as expected.

Now I want to have a default connection from primary scorecard to secondary scorecard. When the dashboard page loads for the first time, I want the first row of the Date dimension i.e. 24 March 2014 to be selected by default and this member to be send to the filter. Is it possible? If yes, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scorecard does not have any Out of the Box feature to provide default filter values as a PerformancePoint filter does. However I was able to exploit the beauty of **Named Sets** to craft a solution of my own to achieve this behavior.

The primary scorecard has Date dimension members on the rows. Currently, the non-empty values are 10 March 2014, 17 March 2014 and 24 March 2014. I have used a Named Set to display non-empty dates in **descending** order.

I have this Named Set (Date dimension) from primary KPI connected to the Page of secondary scorecard. So when we load the page, non of the KPI is selected in the primary scorecard and the secondary scorecard displays the values for whole data without any filtering.

My objective was to have the secondary scorecard displayed as if KPI on 24 March 2014 was selected.

1. Create a new **Named Set** for secondary scorecard that will select only the desired date. In my scenario, it is the latest non-empty date.
2. Drag and drop this new **Named Set** into secondary scorecard.
3. Modify the existing connection between two scorecards as shown below.
   Replace
   ***Member Unique Name -> Page*** connection with something like
   ***Member Unique Name -> /Set*** Formulas ([New Named Set])
   [image]
4. Deploy the dashboard.

Now I have the default value selected in secondary scorecard because of the **new Named Set** in secondary scorecard. And the KPI selection in primary scorecard changes the data in secondary scorecard accordingly.

:) Cheers :)